# Update page with ajax on form submit - nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to do something similar to adding comments to blog posts via ajax but i'm struggling to get it working. In my project, a user can have many activities and each activity can have many items.

The routing is as follows:

```
resources :users do
  resources :activities do
    resources :items
  end  
end
```

**ActivitiesController.rb**

```
#rest of code

def show
  @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
  @new_item = @activity.items.build
  @items = @activity.items.all.order('id DESC')
end
```

**ItemsController.rb**

```
#rest of code
def create

  @activity = Activity.find(params[:activity_id])

  @item = @activity.items.new(item_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @item.save
      format.html {redirect_to user_activity_path(@activity.user_id, @activity)}
      format.js
    else
      format.html {redirect_to :back}
    end
  end
end
```

**activities/show.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="large-6 large-offset-3 columns">

    <%= simple_form_for [@activity, @new_item], url: user_activity_items_path(@activity.user_id, @activity), remote: true do |f| %>

    <%= f.input :name, required: false, :wrapper_html => { class: 'large-8 columns name' } %>
    <%= f.input :cost, required: false, :wrapper_html => { class: 'large-4 columns cost' } %>

    <%= f.submit "Add Item", class: 'large-4 columns button' %>
   <% end %>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">

  <div class="large-6 large-offset-3 columns item-list">

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Cost</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <% @items.each do |item| %>
         <%= render 'item', item: item %>
       <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

**activities/_item.html.erb**

```
<tr>
  <td><%= item.name %></td>
  <td><%= item.cost %></td>
</tr>
```

**items/create.js.erb**

```
#currently empty
```

Comment: Getting store all data fine with out ajax?

Comment: not sure what you mean? if you're asking whether it works without ajax, the answer is yes

Comment: Have you ever use rails ujs?

Comment: not very much, no...

Comment: Okay no problem. can you tell me after saving your data means submitting data what you want to do?

Comment: after submitting form your activity should get updated with newly inserted data, right?

Comment: yea exactly, currently after the form is submitted a full page reload is done and the newly added row of inserted data can be seen in the table so i want that to happen without reload

Comment: Yes sure please check my answer. if you get stuck any where please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your create.js.erb should look like

```
$("#getItems").last('tr').after('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "activities/item", :locals => { :item => @item })) %>');
```

And on show page replace this by mine.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-6 large-offset-3 columns item-list">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Cost</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="getItems">
       <% @items.each do |item| %>
         <%= render 'item', item: item %>
       <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @SSR, i'm getting an `undefined local variable` error on `item` from the `_item.html.erb` partial

Comment: Please check my update in create.js.erb file and replace it with new one.